# Magento2.3 setup:upgrade error

Tags: cli, setup-upgrade, magento2.3

After being able to update magento to 2.3 (which was a pain by itself) I managed to get to the part where the database needs to be updated. Which is in current state when I try to run the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade`:

```
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/generated/code/MSP
/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/generated/code/Symfony
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Cannot process definition to array for type enum
```

I can't however manage to find where this enum thing comes from. I also can't find any errors containing where this enum thing comes from...

anyone knows where this error comes from and how I can debug this? I know this can't lead to a specific page, but where do I need to focus on and how can I find out how I can solve this massive blockage of the site :D

Comment: What is the PHP version you used for Magento 2.3?

Comment: We are currently running php7.2

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/magento2-extension/issues/45 and this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19479

Comment: Kindly please disable all the third party modules & try to run the commands again & then check one by one exactly which third party extension is generating this issue!

Comment: I think this error related to any module for Schema(create or update table)

Comment: Please check my ans here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251920/cannot-process-definition-to-array-for-type-tinytext-on-magento-2-3-0/252467#252467

Comment: it will fix your issue for sure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need to update in core files, please follow up my solution. 
Open Mysql database and select database and use below queries. This query also will be useful to find out the datatype CHAR error when upgrade to Magento 2.3.

> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE ='enum';

Then the table will be list, after that you have to update the column datatype to the acceptable data type like varchar,etc.

> Eg: ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `column_name` VARCHAR(10);

Note: Update only magento table if you have the result using search query not other mysql table.

Try this, thumps up.

Comment: This is the only solution which works. Just a syntax fix (MySQL) use MODIFY instead CHANGE: 

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(10);

Comment: Thanks for the updates.

Answer (score 13):

You are getting this error because "data type" of any third party extension's table column is **enum**.

So you need to find out column name using debug in following file.

See below file /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php and check this **fromDefinition()** and add debug code to find column name.

```
public function fromDefinition(array $data)
{
    $type = $data['type'];
    if (!isset($this->definitionProcessors[$type])) {

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($data); exit();

       throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
       sprintf("Cannot process definition to array for type %s", $type)
            );
    }

    $definitionProcessor = $this->definitionProcessors[$type];
    return $definitionProcessor->fromDefinition($data);
}
```

Please run again **setup:upgrade**  and you will get array of column data in console. from this array you will get name of column from your third party extension table.

Now from that table please change column's data type "**enum**" to "**text**" and issue will be fixed.

REF: [Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext on Magento 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251920/cannot-process-definition-to-array-for-type-tinytext-on-magento-2-3-0/252467#252467)