# Upgrade Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3.4 issue

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade

I am trying to update my magento from 2.1.5 to 2.3.4 and during run my commands i get this error when trying to open admin page,

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'comforte_comfkh.admin_analytics_usage_version_log' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `log_table`.* FROM `admin_analytics_usage_version_log` AS `log_table` ORDER BY `log_table`.`id` desc
```

please advice

Answer (score 0):

During which comment did you receive this error ?

The error is thrown because a table does not exist in your database.

To assure your Database is up to date, execute the following command:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Done and get the below Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
generated/code/Composer
generated/code/Magento
generated/code/Mageside
generated/code/Swissup
generated/code/Symfony
generated/code/Tawk
The directory 'generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
pub/static/_cache
pub/static/deployed_version.txt
pub/static/frontend
var/view_preprocessed/pub
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
<pre>Array
(
    [name] => title
    [default] =>
    [type] => tinytext
    [nullable] => 0
    [definition] => tinytext
    [extra] =>
    [comment] =>
)

Comment: The **<pre>Array ( [name] => title [default] => [type] => tinytext [nullable] => 0 [definition] => tinytext [extra] => [comment] => )** part is strange, looks like there is a dump of information to the cli

Comment: yes I followed this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/288196/magento-2-2-2-to-magento-2-3-2-setupupgrade-error?rq=1 to fix my issue but still can't fix

Comment: when I try to add command php bin/magento setup:upgrade it gives me >> Schema creation/updates:
Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table following this command:

```
  CREATE TABLE `admin_analytics_usage_version_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Log ID',
  `last_viewed_in_version` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Viewer last viewed on product version',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ADMIN_ANALYTICS_USAGE_VERSION_LOG_LAST_VIEWED_IN_VERSION` (`last_viewed_in_version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Notification Viewer Log Table';
```

Does it work?