# Facing an error "Types real is not declared" in Magento 2.3.5 while running setup upgrade

Tags: magento2, database-schema, magento2.3.5

Whenever tries to run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but facing an error as follows:

> "Types real is not declared"

[image]
I know by getting the type name of the Information schema of data type and triggering alter a table that would not be a good approach.

How can I solve this?

PS. recently got upgraded from 2.2 to 2.3.5

Referred this also - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279384