# Magento 2.3 Install failed .... Invalid Index using addColumn method

Tags: magento2.3, installation, magento2.3.0

Installing Magento 2.3, I get error Invalid Index,   the error points to the attached code in the setup   file and error states the index is

> 'tinyint(1) NOT   NULL default 0'

.  Dropped back to 2.2.7, it works  fine.

```
if(!$installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists($installer->getTable('catalog_product_option'),  'customoptions_status')) { 
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn( $installer->getTable('catalog_product_option'),  
                'customoptions_status',  
                'tinyint(1) NOT NULL default 0'
);
}
```

Comment: You should use based data type from Db Class instead of other data type SQL supported.

Answer (score 2):

the 'tinyint' will not work in Magento 2.3 because it is bug in magento latest version, so you must need to change "tinyint" to "int".

Also please check this post for more information about TINYTEXT, TINYINT, ENUM and MEDIUMINT : [Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext on Magento 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251920/cannot-process-definition-to-array-for-type-tinytext-on-magento-2-3-0/252467#252467)

Please check and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Changing to int did not fix issue ..... tried another chunk of code that tried to add a column of varchar, still got the error ...   [ERROR] Exception: Notice: Undefined index: varchar(10) NOT NULL default ''

Comment: are you doing upgrade or fresh install ?

Comment: fresh install ..... works in 2.2.7.

Comment: What is your php and mysql version ?

Comment: PHP 7.2.13  MariaDB 10.1.37   (using Windows)