# Magento 2: Setup Magento project after clone git repository

Tags: magento2, setup, github

I want to set up a git project on my local machine.

I have successfully set up the database.

I have run git clone command and clone the project from git but some repository is blank.

so how can I set up a project in the localhost?

If anyone has a solution then provide

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the `vendor` folder. If it is empty then you need to run the below commands to install core modules of Magento and deploy the project.

```
composer update
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

Check the `composer.json` file first before running the `composer update` command.

> Edit:

Please check the `app/etc` folder it should contain `config.php` and `env.php`. In `env.php`, the database configuration (your local setup) is set.

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: i got this error after run this [Can't run this operation: deployment configuration is absent. Run 'magento setup:config:set --help' for options.]

Comment: Please check the app/etc folder it should contain config.php and env.php with the local database setup details.

Comment: no here only env.php is available but config.php is missing

Comment: You need to add the config.php here before running these commands. Just copy and paste it from your production branch.

Comment: can i copy it from other magento project or menually add a blank file named with config.php ?

Comment: You can copy it from other Magento installation or add it from your production branch.

Comment: after adding config file it work

Comment: but it give me error [Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext] after run setup:upgrade command

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251920/cannot-process-definition-to-array-for-type-tinytext-in-magento-2-3-0

Comment: thank you for providing help it work for me

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to setup project after clone git repository.

- Export working Projects database and then Import Database
- Take Clone / Extract the Source code
- Run the 'composer update' command. (If composer is not installed then run first 'composer install' command and then 'composer update')
- Run php bin/magento setup:config:set --db-user="dbusername" --db-password="dbpassword" --db-name="dbname" (It creates env.php in following path app/etc/env.php)
- Run php bin/magento module:enable --all (It creates config.php in following path app/etc/config.php)
- Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- Run php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- Change base url in database. (Table Name : core_config_data. Change path 'web/unsecure/base_url' & 'web/secure/base_url')
- Ex: http://127.0.0.1/magento2/
- Run php bin/magento cache:clean
- Now open url in browser