# When trying to upgrade I encounter the error "Cannot process definition to array for type time"

Tags: database, error, upgrade, magento2.3.2, cli

I'm getting the following error on Magento 2.3.2 when executing command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> Cannot process definition to array for type time

I'm aware that this is usually caused by a script using `time` but I'm
not sure which extension is using this.

Is there a quick way to check through either the CLI or the database
to find out where it is being used and is there a safe way to change
it to another type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after following the advice at the question posted here:
[Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext in Magento 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251920/cannot-process-definition-to-array-for-type-tinytext-in-magento-2-3-0)

I managed to ascertain that the type field causing the issue was in a backup table for an old extension that I no longer use.

Removing the table with the field in PHPMyadmin fixed the issue but it is also possible to just change the type if the table is still required.